# Angular 8 runtime error after core-js upgrade

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm getting the run time error below after upgrading our Angular application from Angular 7.2 to Angular 8.1 and updating core-js from 2.6.2 to 3.1.4.  Our application does not use the Angular CLI, we just use webpack directly.  Keeping the core-js version at 2.6.2 works just fine.  What is the proper way of loading this polyfill manually with the new version of core-js?

The old polyfill.ts would load core-js as follows:

```
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

I tried the following with the new core-js but no luck:

```
import 'core-js/es'
import 'core-js/es/reflect'
```

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Location: (?, ?).
at syntaxError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:2687)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:21589)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:21481)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableTypeMetadata (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:21704)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:21713)
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:21651)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:21611)
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:21613)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue after reading the core-js version 3 change log and other articles.  This change to how I import the core-js polyfill in polyfill.ts resolved the runtime issue mentioned above:

```
import 'core-js/es';
import 'core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata';
```

Answer (score 0):

Default angular 8 polyfill doesnt contain core-js because the framework already handle core-js it's self so you can remove core-js import in your polyfill

Comment: I removed the core-js from my polyfill.ts file.. same error.